# How can Forgotten Realms maps be used in DMsGuild adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, publishing, maps, intellectual-property, dms-guild

JVC Parry's recent intriguing DMsGuild adventure [Call from the Deep](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/280922) includes a hex map of an area of the Sword Coast from Forgotten Realms.

As JVC Parry is a third-party author outside of WotC, this suggests that DMsGuild allows use or recreation of their maps.

As I understand the DMsGuild guidelines, textual content from books and adventures can be used but not images outside of those that DMsGuild has published specifically for that use.

**What DMsGuild allowed path are authors using to publish Forgotten Realms(FR) maps? Do authors have to recreate them with their own cartographers? Or is there a bank of map images somewhere that DMsGuild has provided?**

Note: As opposed to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143463/is-forgotten-realms-geo-location-data-copyrighted-or-free-to-use?rq=1) which asks about the copyright issues of using Forgotten Realms maps - this question is asking for DMsGuild approved sources of FR maps allowed to DMsGuid authors or approaches that previous authors have taken that DMsGuild allows or states that they allow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be a better fit on Law SE

Comment: @DaleM “it might be on-topic somewhere else” is not, in and of itself, a reason why something is *off*-topic here. In this case, we absolutely handle questions like this. And, personally, I highly doubt Law.SE is likely to be the superior choice for this particular question, since it may well hinge on particular licenses used on DMs Guilde that non-subject-matter experts would have no reason to be aware of, even if they know the law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## DMsGuild replied to us you can use them. Here's how:

DMsGuild responded [with a URL clarifying their policy](https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/217029188-Logo-and-Artwork-Questions).

> **Can I duplicate/redraw existing D&D maps from any edition?**
>
> Duplicated maps, including maps recreated in different art styles, can
>   only be published on Dungeon Masters Guild if they directly support
>   another adventure or supplement. They cannot be the primary product.
>   **If you write an adventure that takes places in a location from an
>   existing D&D adventure, you can include redrawn maps of that location.**
>   You cannot publish the redrawn maps as an independent map pack. For
>   example, if your adventure is set in Luskan, you can include redrawn
>   maps of the city and nearby locations; however, **you cannot publish
>   those redrawn maps as a separate map pack or stock art.**   As maps
>   included in other supplements are artwork, they are not exclusive to
>   DMsGuild, but as they use D&D IP, you should be aware of the Fan
>   Content Policy if using artwork elsewhere.

## We also contacted JVC Parry and this was his reply.

> "The map included in the adventure is by Elven Tower. My understanding
>   is that you cannot draw and sell maps of any existing locations in
>   Faerûn (and probably other settings) to be sold on their own. However,
>   as part of a larger product, you can reproduce maps provided they’re
>   not exact copies.
>
> **In this instance, because there are new locations added and the maps are sold as part of the adventure, not on its own, there’s no issue."**